# My Android Studio doesn't recognize my device

Tags: android, android-studio, smartphone

I'm learning How to develop App Android. I'm using Android Studio. I created a "HelloAndroid" as my first project, but I'd like that running in my Smartphone, but it doesnt't work. When I click in Run app, it open a window for choose a device, but nothing appear. I guess that it doesn't recognized my device. However, I enable developer mode in my cell phone. May anybody help me, please? I already tried all.

My Windows is 8.1 64-bit
Android Studio 1.3.2

Comment: Did you set up the Windows driver? http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Comment: visit your device brand website and download the usb driver. windows plug and play driver wont do.

Comment: No, I didn't. I will test it.

Comment: @Cássia What's the model of your device?

Comment: I installed Lg Mobile usb driver. After, Computer>>Manager Devices>>Portables Devices>>G3 Stylus>>Update Driver>>Find software driver in computer>>C:\Users\Cássia\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver >> Software already installed.

Comment: @Skizo - It's a LG G3 Stylus. So, Now, I'm running app >> Choose  a running device, but doesn't appear my device. There is a message :"Gradle build finished in 4s 240ms (moments ago)".

Comment: @Cássia Use [pdanet](http://pdanet.co/a)

Comment: I installed pdanet, but I can't connected it. Appear this message: "Please make sure your phone usb debugging is enable". But it is enable.

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck in this problem for like 2 days to solve it.

Yeah, there are few ways to resolve this problem.

Case 1. Enable the USB debugging option in your mobile. Setting > developer > **Check "USB Debugging"**

Case 2. Change from **MTP** to **PTP**.(sometimes vise versa works)

Case 3. If nothing worked then try to Install [**PdaNet+**](http://pdanet.co/a/) in your system. This Actually worked for me.

PS: Let me know which of the above case solve your issue.

best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

go to the device manager in windows. see whether USB driver is installed or not.If not installed install it otherwise update the driver. If installed already and your windows machine doesnot still show the device then you need to edit a usb driver file inside Google usb driver folder of android sdk directory...